# Message: "Private zone 'privatelink.queue.core.windows.net' is already linked to the virtual network

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to create Azure private endpoint for Blob, table and queue storages and link virtual network with Azure private DNS zones. I am getting the following error. I am using Azure Private DNS zone groups to create relevant zones.

`````
 Error: creating/updating Virtual Network Link (Subscription: "d2fhaaf8"
│ Resource Group Name: "rg-456"
│ Private Dns Zone Name: "privatelink.queue.core.windows.net"
│ Virtual Network Link Name: "queue_vnet-456_private"): polling after CreateOrUpdate: polling failed: the Azure API returned the following error:
│
│ Status: "Unknown"
│ Code: "Conflict"
│ Message: "Private zone 'privatelink.queue.core.windows.net' is already linked to the virtual network '/subscriptions/d2fhaaf8-/resourceGroups/rg-456/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-456'."
│ Activity Id: ""
│
│ ---
│
│ API Response:
│
│ ----[start]----
│ {"error":{"code":"Conflict","message":"Private zone 'privatelink.queue.core.windows.net' is already linked to the virtual network '\/subscriptions\/d2fhaaf8-\/resourceGroups\/rg-456\/providers\/Microsoft.Network\/virtualNetworks\/vnet-456'."},"status":"Failed"}
│ -----[end]-----
│
│
│   with azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link.private_links["queue"],
│   on main.tf line 282, in resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "private_links":
│  282: resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "private_links" {```


resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "this" {
  for_each = local.endpoints

  name                = "privatelink.${each.value}.core.windows.net"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.this.name
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "this" {
  for_each = azurerm_private_dns_zone.this

  name                  = "${each.key}-vnet-link"
  private_dns_zone_name = azurerm_private_dns_zone.this[each.key].name
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.this.name
  virtual_network_id    = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.id```


}````

i am expecting to link all Azure private dns zones with the virtual network. But i am getting above erros.
`````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried provisioning Azure private endpoint for Blob, table and queue storages and link virtual network with Azure private DNS zone and I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

The private DNS zone `privatelink.queue.core.windows.net` you're trying to link to the virtual network `vnet-456` is already linked to this virtual network. This is causing a conflict because you're attempting to create a link that already exists.

Your Terraform configuration is trying to create private DNS zones and link them to a virtual network. The `for_each` loop iterates over `local.endpoints`, creating a private DNS zone for each endpoint. Then, it tries to create a virtual network link for each of these DNS zones.

The problem occurred because there was already a resource in the portal before you ran the code. To avoid this, please do the following checks:

1. **Check Existing State**: Ensure that the Azure state and the Terraform state are in sync. If the resources already exist in Azure but Terraform is unaware, it could try to create them again, leading to conflicts.
2. **Modify Terraform Code**: You may need to adjust your Terraform code to handle cases where a link already exists. One way to do this is by using a data source to check if the link exists before creating it.
3. **Error Handling**: Implement error handling or conditionals in your Terraform code to gracefully skip or update existing resources instead of attempting to recreate them.

**My terraform code:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "this" {
  name     = "rg-456"
  location = "East US"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = "vnet-456"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.this.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.this.location
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "this" {
  for_each = toset(["blob", "table", "queue"])

  name                = "privatelink.${each.value}.core.windows.net"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.this.name
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "this" {
  for_each = azurerm_private_dns_zone.this

  name                  = "${each.key}-vnet-link"
  private_dns_zone_name = azurerm_private_dns_zone.this[each.key].name
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.this.name
  virtual_network_id    = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.id
  depends_on            = [azurerm_private_dns_zone.this]
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]